# Font suggestions for a church site

Tags: website-design, font-recommendation

Do you guys have any font suggestions for a ministry website (for headlines, logo etc.) ?

So far I found this one:

[image]

Comment: What kind of an image the church would like to give to the visitors? What is the purpose of the site? What is its (planned) target audience?

Comment: +1 to Koiyu. "Who is this for" is one of (if not) the most important question when designing anything.

Comment: The one you picked is as good as any. Without a lot more context, we can only toss out purely subjective suggestions.

Comment: Yeah, without more info, I'm gonna have to go with Comic Sans.

Comment: Give 'Jesus Loves You All' a try: http://www.lucasfonts.com/fonts/jesuslovesyouall/jesuslovesyouall/overview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're going for a more formal look for your church. I would use a Transitional Type font, which is similar to the font you've chosen above (Fanwood).

I have a few fonts in mind that might work for you. If you like small x-heights (similar to Fanwood) you could go with ITC or Adobe Garamond. It's a classy font though I don't recommend it for logos set in lower case or title case.

If you like fonts with larger x-heights, you could try Miller or Whitman by Font Bureau, http://new.myfonts.com/foundry/Font_Bureau/. There's also ITC Century and ITC New Baskerville, both common system fonts. Another nice font is Calluna by Exljbris Font Foundry, http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/exljbris/calluna/. One font that I really like is Latienne, which can be found on myfonts.com, but it's also a very feminine font and might not be the best direction for you. I recommend it because the Medium could look really nice and has a lot of potential for a logo.

Answer (score 1):

Given that's an image not a link I don't know if you already have that font. If not, here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/fanwood

As far as suggestions for other fonts, the main thing is from that one you picked it looks like you want to look at mostly serif fonts because they are more formal looking:
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/style/Serif

This one on their front page looks pretty good: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Calluna

Answer (score 1):

#### The gothic look of [Priori](http://www.emigre.com/fontpage.php?PPriSanItal.html) and [Mason](http://www.emigre.com/fontpage.php?PMasSe.html) would work for a church website.

[image]